# Algorithms for solving Flow game

Tags: graphs, colorings

Lately I've been toying with an automatic solver for the Android/iPhone game [Flow](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigduckgames.flow&hl=en).

In this game, you start with several pairs of squares on a grid, and you have to connect each pair, without crossing the paths, and by using every square on the grid. Here's a simple 7x7 example (the hardest boards in the game are 11x13).

Beginning:

[image: Beginning layout]

Finished:

[image: Finished board]

In most cases, a few simple rules can all but solve the problem. For example, if a node only has one uncovered exit, it must extend that way, and if extending in a direction would make a part of the board unreachable, then that move is forbidden. But is there a more general way? I've been trying to figure out if it is a specific case of a general graph algorithm, perhaps some kind of [Path Coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_coloring).

Note that the game presents other variants of the problem, such as a hexagonal grid, and 'warps' that connect squares on opposite sides of the board. Also, as far as I can tell, there is only ever one correct solution. I'd also be interested in how they can generate the starting positions.

Comment: related: ​ ​ ​ [my question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/31938/12859) ​ and ​ [domotorp's question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/37281/6973) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Thank you, you're right, my cursory searches didn't turn those up. I'll have to investigate those papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest formulating this as an instance of SAT.

You can formulate this as an instance of SAT by thinking of it as trying to color each square in the grid with a color.  For each color, arbitrarily designate one of the two endpoints as the "starting position" for that color, and the other endpoint as the "ending position".  Define boolean variables $x_{i,j,c,k}$, with the intended meaning that $x_{i,j,c,k}$ is true if grid square $(i,j)$ is colored $c$ and is the $k$th square along the path from the starting position for $c$ to the ending position for $c$.

You can write down a boolean formula representing the constraints on the variables $x_{i,j,c,k}$ that must hold, for this to be a valid solution to the puzzle.  For instance:

- If $x_{i,j,c,k}$ is true, then either $(i,j)$ must be the end position for color $c$, or else $x_{i',j',c,k+1}$ must be true for some square $(i',j')$ that is adjacent to $(i,j)$.  Moreover, this is true for exactly two squares (not more, not less), unless $(i,j)$ is the starting position, in which case it is true for exactly one square.
- For each square $(i,j)$, exactly one of the $x_{i,j,c,k}$ is true.
- If $(i,j)$ is the starting position for color $c$, $x_{i,j,c,0}$ is true.  If $(i,j)$ is the ending position for color $c$, one of $x_{i,j,c,k}$ must be true.

And so on.  This ensures that the solution to the formula contains a path that starts at the starting position for color $c$ and ends at the ending position.

Then, feel this boolean formula to an off-the-shelf SAT solver and ask it to find a solution.

This may be an effective solution for the puzzle sizes you mention. I expect it may be more effective than trying to write your own custom rules, as SAT solvers embody many clever strategies built up over decades of research to try to find solutions for these kinds of combinatorial questions.  At least, it should be pretty easy to implement in just a few hours and see how well it works.

Apparently, this puzzle [is NP-hard](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/31938/755), so you should not expect to find a polynomial-time solution.  This suggests to me that a SAT solver might be a reasonable approach.

Comment: How could he write down such a formula? ​ (I don't see how to force the $\hspace{1.91 in}$ non-existence of disconnected cycles.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer, oops, you're right.  When I get a chance I'll update my answer with a correct construction.

Comment: @RickyDemer, see updated answer.  I think this should do it.  Widjet, see updated answer. I think this should now provide a reasonable algorithm for your problem.

Comment: I should have accepted this months ago, I'm sorry. It appears this is approximately the approach used by the papers mentioned by @RickyDemer in the comment on the question. I don't know if I'll ever get around to trying to implement it myself, but it's probably the right answer.

Comment: I find this answer fascinating.  Some years ago I wrote a brute-force solver for this game.  Many ended up being solvable in sensible time, but almost always needed an extended stack (I was using java) and then of course, one or two would take weeks to finish.  It's up to its eyeballs with heuristics to try to speed things up.  But I've been *struggling* to find a way to manage this without state, in a functional way to spread across multiple cores.

Comment: Ok, I'm having trouble figuring out this answer in direct implementable ways.  Can someone point me out to a good tutorial for implementing such SAT strategies as might apply to this question?

Comment: @tgm1024, you could try https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/30790/755, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12087/755.

Comment: @D.W., Ok, I'm becoming increasingly impressed.  I have to say that Way Back In College® (80's, just shoot me), I was wondering if a Karnaugh Map style of equation simplification could be applied to some sort of algorithm distillation.  Or less clumsy words to that effect.  I'll have to dive into this better.  I'm still trying to figure out how (in the flow example) if multiple possible solutions result in NP-Complete'ness and/or how it "chooses" between them.  Man, I have to dust off quite a bit from that part of my brain.